# selecting from table where timestamp is latest

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

i have made a table for an audit trail.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `audit_trail_timer` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `remaining_duration` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_id`)
)
```

now i wanted to select a row where the timestamp is the most recent one.

```
$query = select * from audit_trail_timer where user_id='$id' and timestamp='';
```

Comment: most recent one ? its subjective, by most recent one what do you expect today, last one week, last one month ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty most recent as in the latest one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   try this

   SELECT * FROM audit_trail_timer WHERE user_id='$id' 
    ORDER BY TIMESTAMP  DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

SELECT top 1 * FROM audit_trail_timer WHERE user_id='$id' 
    ORDER BY TIMESTAMP  DESC;

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
  SELECT * FROM audit_trail_timer WHERE user_id='$id' 
  ORDER BY   TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT * 
FROM audit_trail_timer 
WHERE user_id = '$id'
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
LIMIT 1
```

`timestamp` is reserved keyword

Comment: No `timestamp`,`date` and few are not reserved in mysql since they are often used.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Right, however I always try to avoid using this kind of keywords ; )

Comment: Yes thats better to avoid these kind of keyword but for a newbie its really hard for them since mostly when we learned we never had any idea of reserved words, so as a safe side use backtick or read complete documentation of mysql.